# Getting :before content and printing special characters from content

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the `content` from my `:before` tag. I know some will say it's not a real (*pseudo*) element but there is a way in JS but can some one help me do it in JQ because I have multiple tags and I want to iterate with `$.each`...

Here is how I got the `content` in JS

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('i'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content')
```

**How can I do this in JQ?**

Here is what I tried:

```
$.each($('div'),function(){
 $(this).find('i:before').css('content');
});
```

### Print a special char?

When I get the `content` I would like to print it, the problem is it's a special character and I would like to get a real code.

My `content` has a code like this: `\e002`. So I would like to print it like that not ``.

Comment: `:before` is not a DOM element you cant access to it.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: @John Yes you can access it I provided the code

Comment: @ZachButtram It is not a duplicate because it doesn't show how to do it in JQ and also how do I print special characters ?

Comment: Within the `$.each()`, you could try `window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').getPropertyValue('content')`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thank you rick for the answer that solves a smaller problem, is there a way to print a special charterer code. So for example I want to print a code like `&copy;` not `©`... I even tried `<pre>` :D

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate `$.each($('div i')` instead of `$.each($('div')`, so you can avoid using `find()` within the iterator.

You can then use your `window.getComputedStyle()` code on `this`:

```
window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').getPropertyValue('content')
```

You'll then be left with a Unicode string, which brings us to the second part of your question.

You can use **[charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)** to view this string character by character, which gives the following for `\e002`:

- 34
- 57346
- 34

The `34`s represent double-quotes, which you can ignore.

`57346` is the decimal equivalent of hexadecimal `e002`.  You can use **[toString(16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)** to convert it to hex.

All that's left is to prepend the `\` in front.

So our code becomes:

```
$.each($('div i'),function() {
  var s = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').getPropertyValue('content'),
      char = '\\' + s.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);

  console.log(char);  // \e002
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$.each($('div i'),function() {
  var s = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').getPropertyValue('content'),
      char = '\\' + s.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);
  
  console.log(char);  // \e002
});
```

```css
i:before {
  content: '\e002';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <i>Our italic node</i>
</div>
```

Comment: That was the exact thing I was looking for.. Did not know about `charCodeAt`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!